# Как правильно установить библиотеки для MultipartEntity?

Tags: android, android-studio

Приводить все примеры не буду, что я только не пробовал. Не дает откомпилировать проект. Вот последний код тоже где-то с хешкода дернул:

> compile group:
> 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name:
> 'httpclient-android' , version:
> '4.3.5.1'
> compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3')
> {
>     exclude module: "httpclient" }

Ошибки:

> Information:Gradle tasks
> [:app:assembleDebug] :app:preBuild
> :app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
> :app:preDebugBuild
> :app:checkDebugManifest
> :app:preReleaseBuild
> :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72103Library
> UP-TO-DATE
> :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42103Library
> UP-TO-DATE
> :app:prepareDebugDependencies
> :app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
> :app:compileDebugRenderscript
> UP-TO-DATE
> :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
> UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugAssets
> UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugAssets
> UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugResValues
> UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugResources
> UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugResources
> UP-TO-DATE :app:processDebugManifest
> UP-TO-DATE :app:processDebugResources
> UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugSources
> UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugJava
> UP-TO-DATE :app:preDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
> :app:dexDebug UP-TO-DATE
> :app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
> :app:validateDebugSigning
> :app:packageDebug Error:duplicate
> files during packaging of APK
> D:\android\workspace\MyApp\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug-unaligned.apk
>   Path in archive: META-INF/LICENSE
>   Origin 1:
> C:\Users\Admin.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.httpcomponents\httpmime\4.3\5b0002c5fb66867ca919be0fbd86de1cfaf76da7\httpmime-4.3.jar
>   Origin 2:
> C:\Users\Admin.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.httpcomponents\httpclient-android\4.3.5.1\eecbb0b998e77629862a13d957d552b3be58fc4e\httpclient-android-4.3.5.1.jar
> You can ignore those files in your
> build.gradle:     android {  
> packagingOptions {
>       exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'    }     } Error:Execution failed for task
> ':app:packageDebug'.
>
> > Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE  File 1:
> > C:\Users\Admin.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.httpcomponents\httpmime\4.3\5b0002c5fb66867ca919be0fbd86de1cfaf76da7\httpmime-4.3.jar
> >   File 2:
> > C:\Users\Admin.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.httpcomponents\httpmime\4.3\5b0002c5fb66867ca919be0fbd86de1cfaf76da7\httpmime-4.3.jar
> > Information:BUILD FAILED
> > Information:Total time: 3.903 secs
> > Information:2 errors Information:0
> > warnings Information:See complete
> > output in console

Опишите подробно куда то добавлять что нормально работал MultipartEntity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все, вроде разобрался, скинул нужные библиотеки в папку проекта libs и прописал в Grandle такие строки:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}
```

Вроде заработало. )